# NPM Package for relational POS tagging/parse tree? (i.e. identify subject and object, not just noun/verb/adjective)

Tags: node.js, npm, nlp, pos-tagger

I'm working on a project where I scrape an Esports Wiki for player transfers, team changes, etc. I've gotten to the point where I can isolate a string like "Sizz joins NRG Esports as coach," and from this string I want to identify the player, team, and type of event. The phrasing of these strings is straightforward, but not always consistent, for example "team drops player" or "player leaves team" should result in the same event being parsed. Sometimes, a string will also contain multiple events, so I haven't been able to use keywords or anything like that.

What I'm looking for is something that will take in a sentence and spit out a parse tree with relation POS tagging, like this:

[image]

Or, in text form:

```
( (IP-MAT (NP-SBJ (PRO I))
  (VP (VBP enjoy)
      (NP-OB1 (N hunting)))
  (PUNC .)))
```

Where -sbj and -obj are tags, not just NP, VP, etc.

[spacy-nlp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/spacy-nlp) seems to do it, but it uses socket.io and Python, which seems like a lot. [CoreNLP](https://www.npmjs.com/package/corenlp) seems similarly promising, as it uses Stanford's big CoreNLP project, but again this uses Java. [Compromise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compromise) seemed like a really good, lightweight solution, but while it works well for identifying nouns/verbs/adjectives/etc., it doesn't seem to have any functionality for relation tagging (subject and object).

I've been looking for hours and am considering just redoing my entire project in Python at this point, but this seems like a simple enough task that some JS NLP solution should be able to handle it. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to use the pos tagged text and determine noun or verb phrases on the basis of rules. [Wink NLP, a node.js NPM package](https://winkjs.org/wink-nlp/), allows you to develop your own rules to define and detect [custom entities](https://winkjs.org/wink-nlp/custom-entities.html) — something that you can use to detect noun/verb phrases.